# Pure html and SignalR login page

Tags: c#, signalr

How can I create working login page using only `SignalR` and `html`? For `Forms Authentication`.

I know how to use SignalR when Auth cookie is created. But I don`t know to make browser create auth cookie.

How can I browser create aspform authentication cookie? document.cookies creates cookie, but SignalR is not sending it back.

When I have Login.aspx, then it makes somehow the cookie and SignalR is sending it. But I would like to use only html and SignalR

Comment: Login.aspx .... brings back old and bad memories.

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` object will not be available in `SignalR.Hub` classes and you also have to tweak `Forms Authentication` to work on non-asp.net files.

So, I don't really see a point in this exercise unless I'm missing something out in your question.

Feel free to add more details and I'll update my answer.

In the meantime, have a look at this tutorial: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

It would be better to authenticate your users first, and then direct them to a page that opens-up a socket for them.